# SQL: Need help with query construction

Tags: sql

I  am relatively new with sql and I need some help with some basic query construction.

**Problem**: To retrieve the number of orders and the customer id from a table based on a set of parameters.

I want to write a query to figure out the number of orders under each customer (Column: Customerid) along with the CustomerID where the number of orders should be greater or equal to 10 and the status of the order should be Active. Moreover, I also want to know the first transaction date of an order belonging to each customerid.

**Table Description:**

product_orders

```
Orderid CustomerId Transaction_date Status
------- ---------- ---------------- -------
 1       23         2-2-10          Active
 2       22         2-3-10          Active
 3       23         2-3-10          Deleted
 4       23         2-3-10          Active
```

**Query that I have written:**

```
select count(*), customerid
  from product_orders
 where status = 'Active'
 GROUP BY customerid
 ORDER BY customerid;
```

The above statement gives me

- the sum of all order under a customer
  id but does not fulfil the condition
  of atleast 10 orders.
- I donot know how
  to display the first transaction date
  along with the order under a
  customerid (status: could be active
  or delelted doesn't matter)

**Ideal solutions should look like:**

```
Total Orders CustomerID Transaction Date (the first transaction date)
------------ ---------- ----------------
11           23         1-2-10
```

Thanks in advance. I hope you guys would be kind enough to stop by and help me out.

Cheers,

Leonidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS [Total Orders],
    CustomerID,
    MIN(Transaction_date) AS [Transaction Date]
FROM product_orders
WHERE product_orders.Status = 'Active'
GROUP BY
    CustomerId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` will allow you to filter aggregates like `COUNT()` & `MIN()` will show the first date.

```
select 
  count(*), 
  customerid, 
  MIN(order_date) 
from product_orders 
  where status = 'Active' 
  GROUP BY customerid
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
  ORDER BY customerid
```

If you want the earliest date irrespective of status you can sub-query for it

```
select 
  count(*), 
  customerid, 
  (SELECT min(order_date) FROM product_orders WHERE product_orders.customerid = p.customerid) AS FirstDate
from product_orders P 
  where status = 'Active' 
  GROUP BY customerid
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
  ORDER BY customerid
```

Comment: Aren't subqueries in the list of fields slow? I have seen a query that runs about 180 secs on Oracle because of such subqueries. Rewriting query so that the same data (`FirstDate` in yo example) is retrieved from "pseudo-view" (i.e., subquery that is used as a data source; not sure how it's called) which is `join`-ed to other data sources reducted time to 0.1, 0.2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the total active orders for each customer that has 10 or more active orders.  It will also display the first active order date.

```
Select  Count(OrderId) as TotalOrders,
        CustomerId,
        Min(Transaction_Date) as FirstActiveOrder

From Product_Orders
Where [Status] = 'Active'
Group By CustomerId
Having Count(OrderId)>10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), customerid,  MIN(Transaction_date) from product_orders
     where status = 'Active'
     GROUP BY customerid having  count(*) >= 10
     ORDER BY customerid
```